# What performs better: Bunch of UNION queries vs separate queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have a custom store site that uses a set of rules (7 to be more precise) to locate parts for the user when he/she presses the buy button. Some of these rules are something like:

- Look for first seller on the same state, city and district as the consumer (only one seller per district is allowed)
- If the seller above doesn't have the part, get a seller of the same group as the one above and is on the same city
- If the above seller doesn't have the part, get a seller that is on the same city
- and so on...

I've worked out a series of queries and got about 300 lines of SQL (formatted for easy reading) in a giant union of each rule wapped in with a top to bring only the first result found.

I'm not sure if this is the better thing to do or is it better to do 7 conditional round trips in sequence checking if the later one has the result before calling the next one.

I estimate that the majority of users will fall through rule 4, thats 4 round trips to SQL Server, just to get a part and the result of the giant union query returns in less than a second in a less than 100,000 parts table.

Problem is, if this site begins to grow up in therms of available parts and users would it be better to leave SQL Server handle the work with the giant query that returns only what I need in 1 trip or is it better to call separate queries?

We are using classic ASP for this job (Yeah! Old school, you know?) if this would be relevant in any case.

Let me know if you need to take a look at the query itself.

**Edit:**

Just for conclusion, here is the query I'm using now:

```
SELECT TOP 1 regras.ids, regras.idCadastro, regras.regra, e.descricao AS nomeEstado, cd.descricao AS nomeCidade, b.nome AS nomeBairro
FROM ( 
    SELECT dbo.group_concat(idPecaItem) AS ids, idCadastro, '1' AS regra 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT TOP 2 idPecaItem, idCadastro 
        FROM pecasItens 
        WHERE COALESCE(pecasItens.idCadastro, 0) = (CASE WHEN EXISTS( 
            SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(pi.idCadastro, 0) 
            FROM pecasItens pi  
            LEFT JOIN cadastros c ON pi.idCadastro = c.idCadastro 
            WHERE (pi.idCadastro IS NULL OR c.tipoParceiro = 'c') AND idPeca = 31740 AND idPedidoItem IS NULL AND dataEntrada <= '2014-3-13' AND devolucaoSolicitada IS NULL
            GROUP BY pi.idCadastro 
            HAVING COUNT(pi.idPecaItem) >= 2
        ) THEN ( 
            SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(pi.idCadastro, 0) 
            FROM pecasItens pi  
            LEFT JOIN cadastros c ON pi.idCadastro = c.idCadastro 
            WHERE (pi.idCadastro IS NULL OR c.tipoParceiro = 'c') AND idPeca = 31740 AND idPedidoItem IS NULL AND dataEntrada <= '2014-3-13' AND devolucaoSolicitada IS NULL
            GROUP BY pi.idCadastro 
            HAVING COUNT(pi.idPecaItem) >= 2
        ) ELSE NULL END) 
         AND idPeca = 31740 AND idPedidoItem IS NULL AND dataEntrada <= '2014-3-13' AND devolucaoSolicitada IS NULL
    ) regra1 
    GROUP BY idCadastro

    UNION  

    SELECT dbo.group_concat(idPecaItem) AS ids, idCadastro, '2' AS regra 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT TOP 2 idPecaItem, idCadastro 
        FROM pecasItens 
        WHERE COALESCE(pecasItens.idCadastro, 0) = (CASE WHEN EXISTS( 
            SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(pi.idCadastro, 0) 
            FROM pecasItens pi  
            LEFT JOIN cadastros c ON pi.idCadastro = c.idCadastro AND c.tipoParceiro = 'r' AND c.idCadastroGrupo = 1
            WHERE pi.idCadastro IS NOT NULL  AND idPeca = 31740 AND idPedidoItem IS NULL AND dataEntrada <= '2014-3-13' AND devolucaoSolicitada IS NULL
            GROUP BY pi.idCadastro 
            HAVING COUNT(pi.idPecaItem) >= 2
        ) THEN ( 
            SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(pi.idCadastro, 0) 
            FROM pecasItens pi  
            LEFT JOIN cadastros c ON pi.idCadastro = c.idCadastro AND c.tipoParceiro = 'r' AND c.idCadastroGrupo = 1
            WHERE pi.idCadastro IS NOT NULL  AND idPeca = 31740 AND idPedidoItem IS NULL AND dataEntrada <= '2014-3-13' AND devolucaoSolicitada IS NULL
            GROUP BY pi.idCadastro 
            HAVING COUNT(pi.idPecaItem) >= 2
        ) ELSE NULL END) 
         AND idPeca = 31740 AND idPedidoItem IS NULL AND dataEntrada <= '2014-3-13' AND devolucaoSolicitada IS NULL
    ) regra2 
    GROUP BY idCadastro 

    UNION 

    SELECT dbo.group_concat(idPecaItem) AS ids, idCadastro, '3' AS regra 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT TOP 2 idPecaItem, idCadastro 
        FROM pecasItens 
        WHERE COALESCE(pecasItens.idCadastro, 0) = (CASE WHEN EXISTS( 
            SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(pi.idCadastro, 0) 
            FROM pecasItens pi  
            LEFT JOIN cadastros c ON pi.idCadastro = c.idCadastro AND c.tipoParceiro = 'r' AND c.idCadastroGrupo = 1
            INNER JOIN cadastrosCidades cc ON c.idCadastro = cc.idCadastro AND cc.idCidade = 4850
            WHERE pi.idCadastro IS NOT NULL  AND idPeca = 31740 AND idPedidoItem IS NULL AND dataEntrada <= '2014-3-13' AND devolucaoSolicitada IS NULL
            GROUP BY pi.idCadastro 
            HAVING COUNT(pi.idPecaItem) >= 2
        ) THEN ( 
            SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(pi.idCadastro, 0) 
            FROM pecasItens pi  
            LEFT JOIN cadastros c ON pi.idCadastro = c.idCadastro AND c.tipoParceiro = 'r' AND c.idCadastroGrupo = 1
            INNER JOIN cadastrosCidades cc ON c.idCadastro = cc.idCadastro AND cc.idCidade = 4850
            WHERE pi.idCadastro IS NOT NULL  AND idPeca = 31740 AND idPedidoItem IS NULL AND dataEntrada <= '2014-3-13' AND devolucaoSolicitada IS NULL
            GROUP BY pi.idCadastro 
            HAVING COUNT(pi.idPecaItem) >= 2
        ) ELSE NULL END) 
         AND idPeca = 31740 AND idPedidoItem IS NULL AND dataEntrada <= '2014-3-13' AND devolucaoSolicitada IS NULL
    ) regra3 
    GROUP BY idCadastro 
    UNION  

    SELECT dbo.group_concat(idPecaItem) AS ids, idCadastro, '4' AS regra 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT TOP 2 idPecaItem, idCadastro 
        FROM pecasItens 
        WHERE COALESCE(pecasItens.idCadastro, 0) = (CASE WHEN EXISTS( 
            SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(pi.idCadastro, 0) 
            FROM pecasItens pi  
            INNER JOIN cadastros c ON pi.idCadastro = c.idCadastro AND c.tipoParceiro = 'r' 
            INNER JOIN cadastrosGrupos cg ON c.idCadastroGrupo = cg.idCadastroGrupo AND cg.idMarca = 2
            INNER JOIN cadastrosCidades cc ON c.idCadastro = cc.idCadastro AND cc.idCidade = 4850
            WHERE pi.idCadastro IS NOT NULL  AND idPeca = 31740 AND idPedidoItem IS NULL AND dataEntrada <= '2014-3-13' AND devolucaoSolicitada IS NULL
            GROUP BY pi.idCadastro 
            HAVING COUNT(pi.idPecaItem) >= 2
        ) THEN ( 
            SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(pi.idCadastro, 0) 
            FROM pecasItens pi  
            INNER JOIN cadastros c ON pi.idCadastro = c.idCadastro AND c.tipoParceiro = 'r' 
            INNER JOIN cadastrosGrupos cg ON c.idCadastroGrupo = cg.idCadastroGrupo AND cg.idMarca = 2
            INNER JOIN cadastrosCidades cc ON c.idCadastro = cc.idCadastro AND cc.idCidade = 4850
            WHERE pi.idCadastro IS NOT NULL  AND idPeca = 31740 AND idPedidoItem IS NULL AND dataEntrada <= '2014-3-13' AND devolucaoSolicitada IS NULL
            GROUP BY pi.idCadastro 
            HAVING COUNT(pi.idPecaItem) >= 2
        ) ELSE NULL END) 
         AND idPeca = 31740 AND idPedidoItem IS NULL AND dataEntrada <= '2014-3-13' AND devolucaoSolicitada IS NULL
    ) regra4 
    GROUP BY idCadastro 

    UNION  

    SELECT dbo.group_concat(idPecaItem) AS ids, idCadastro, '5' AS regra 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT TOP 2 idPecaItem, idCadastro 
        FROM pecasItens 
        WHERE COALESCE(pecasItens.idCadastro, 0) = (CASE WHEN EXISTS( 
            SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(pi.idCadastro, 0) 
            FROM pecasItens pi 
            INNER JOIN cadastrosGrupos cg ON pi.idCadastro = cg.idCadastroMontadora AND cg.idCadastroGrupo = 1
            WHERE pi.idCadastro IS NOT NULL  AND idPeca = 31740 AND idPedidoItem IS NULL AND dataEntrada <= '2014-3-13' AND devolucaoSolicitada IS NULL
            GROUP BY pi.idCadastro 
            HAVING COUNT(pi.idPecaItem) >= 2
        ) THEN ( 
            SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(pi.idCadastro, 0) 
            FROM pecasItens pi 
            INNER JOIN cadastrosGrupos cg ON pi.idCadastro = cg.idCadastroMontadora AND cg.idCadastroGrupo = 1
            WHERE pi.idCadastro IS NOT NULL  AND idPeca = 31740 AND idPedidoItem IS NULL AND dataEntrada <= '2014-3-13' AND devolucaoSolicitada IS NULL
            GROUP BY pi.idCadastro 
            HAVING COUNT(pi.idPecaItem) >= 2
        ) ELSE NULL END) 
         AND idPeca = 31740 AND idPedidoItem IS NULL AND dataEntrada <= '2014-3-13' AND devolucaoSolicitada IS NULL
    ) regra5 
    GROUP BY idCadastro 

    UNION  

    SELECT dbo.group_concat(idPecaItem) AS ids, idCadastro, '6' AS regra 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT TOP 2 idPecaItem, idCadastro 
        FROM pecasItens 
        WHERE COALESCE(pecasItens.idCadastro, 0) = (CASE WHEN EXISTS( 
            SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(pi.idCadastro, 0) 
            FROM pecasItens pi  
            LEFT JOIN cadastros c ON pi.idCadastro = c.idCadastro AND c.tipoParceiro = 'r' AND c.idEstado = 25 AND c.atendeEstadoTodo = 1 
            WHERE pi.idCadastro IS NOT NULL  AND idPeca = 31740 AND idPedidoItem IS NULL AND dataEntrada <= '2014-3-13' AND devolucaoSolicitada IS NULL
            GROUP BY pi.idCadastro 
            HAVING COUNT(pi.idPecaItem) >= 2
        ) THEN ( 
            SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(pi.idCadastro, 0) 
            FROM pecasItens pi  
            LEFT JOIN cadastros c ON pi.idCadastro = c.idCadastro AND c.tipoParceiro = 'r' AND c.idEstado = 25 AND c.atendeEstadoTodo = 1 
            WHERE pi.idCadastro IS NOT NULL  AND idPeca = 31740 AND idPedidoItem IS NULL AND dataEntrada <= '2014-3-13' AND devolucaoSolicitada IS NULL
            GROUP BY pi.idCadastro 
            HAVING COUNT(pi.idPecaItem) >= 2
        ) ELSE NULL END) 
         AND idPeca = 31740 AND idPedidoItem IS NULL AND dataEntrada <= '2014-3-13' AND devolucaoSolicitada IS NULL
    ) regra6 
    GROUP BY idCadastro 

    UNION  

    SELECT dbo.group_concat(idPecaItem) AS ids, idCadastro, '7' AS regra 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT TOP 2 idPecaItem, idCadastro 
        FROM pecasItens 
        WHERE COALESCE(pecasItens.idCadastro, 0) = (CASE WHEN EXISTS( 
            SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(pi.idCadastro, 0) 
            FROM pecasItens pi  
            LEFT JOIN cadastros c ON pi.idCadastro = c.idCadastro AND c.tipoParceiro = 'r' AND c.atendeBrasilTodo = 1 
            WHERE pi.idCadastro IS NOT NULL  AND idPeca = 31740 AND idPedidoItem IS NULL AND dataEntrada <= '2014-3-13' AND devolucaoSolicitada IS NULL
            GROUP BY pi.idCadastro 
            HAVING COUNT(pi.idPecaItem) >= 2
        ) THEN ( 
            SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(pi.idCadastro, 0) 
            FROM pecasItens pi  
            LEFT JOIN cadastros c ON pi.idCadastro = c.idCadastro AND c.tipoParceiro = 'r' AND c.atendeBrasilTodo = 1 
            WHERE pi.idCadastro IS NOT NULL  AND idPeca = 31740 AND idPedidoItem IS NULL AND dataEntrada <= '2014-3-13' AND devolucaoSolicitada IS NULL
            GROUP BY pi.idCadastro 
            HAVING COUNT(pi.idPecaItem) >= 2
        ) ELSE NULL END) 
         AND idPeca = 31740 AND idPedidoItem IS NULL AND dataEntrada <= '2014-3-13' AND devolucaoSolicitada IS NULL
    ) regra7 
    GROUP BY idCadastro 
) regras 
LEFT JOIN cadastros c ON regras.idCadastro = c.idCadastro 
LEFT JOIN listaEstados e ON c.idEstado = e.idEstado 
LEFT JOIN listaCidades cd ON c.idCidade = cd.idCidade 
LEFT JOIN listaBairros b ON c.idBairro = b.idBairro 
ORDER BY regra ASC
```

No, it's not MySQL. `group_concat()` here is a custom aggregate from this guys http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/

Comment: How do you think, is it necessary to look at the query at this point?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't got it. English isn't my home language. I suppose you are being ironic and is telling me to post the query. Is it right, funny?

Comment: Beware of Premature Optimization ("http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization")! But good to think of it anyhow.  Think of it this way...you have two choices so you could switch your process mid-stream if it becomes a bottleneck.  Optionality is good here.  I would tend to push these into a union, especially if the underlying queries would only be used in this context.  A third option would be to return a recordset filtered (which Sql is great at) to 100 records or so and do the decision making in code (and unit test how you make the decision).

Comment: Even if you have four round-trips on average, your performance is going to suffer a lot.

Comment: @BlackjacketMack I'm aware of premature optimization but I think this case is more about a better way to follow up with the next cases that can involve this kind of rules. Anyway, the results filtered with common parammeters can be a big data set. Wouldn't it be worse to return more data to process on IIS? Wouldn't a bigger payload be worse in this case, since classic ASP (VBScript) is not the fastest language out there?

Comment: Hmmm...interesting constraints.  Since this is processed in classic ASP I would say that pushing some logic to the db using a UNION would be the right path.  Otherwise, as you mention, it becomes an issue of payload.  Ideally you could have a decent well filtered query return a pretty compact resultset that you then evaluate in code.  Clearly here there are judgment calls about what 'compact' is.  I would say one query with a UNION should work fine.  Do be aware that 'Top 1' can be slow as a dog if you use 'Order By' (but you won't need to order your results).

Comment: If you are curious about what I've done, take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In nearly all instances the RDBMS is in a much better position to get you the first row.

If your query looks like this,

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (
    SELECT ... FROM ... -- Query #1
UNION ALL
    SELECT ... FROM ... -- Query #2
UNION ALL
    ...
UNION ALL
    SELECT ... FROM ... -- Query #7
)
```

the optimizer is smart enough to stop the query at whatever is the rule that produces the result that you need, be it rule one, rule four, or rule seven. On top of that, the optimizer can run your queries in parallel. Because it sits much closer to your data, it's hard to imagine that you could "outsmart" it by moving part of the query logic away from your RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks, this is how I've done it. I'm curious if this would not kill performance when the number of concurrent accesses grow-up, but didn't know about the optimizer stopping when it founds the result. Good to know.

Comment: May you clarify me something more? Are theses queries returned in order of execution? Lets say I have `select top 1 * from (select x, 1 as q from tbl where y = 1 union select x, 2 as q from tbl where y = 2) tb order by q asc`. Is the order by required to guarantee that rules will return in order or this will only kill some more performance?

Comment: @rcdmk The order of `UNION` is not guaranteed - you may get your data in arbitrary order, which may not even be the same for the same RDBMS. Good optimizer may run the individual SELECTs in parallel, so you get the row that "wins the race". Adding an `ORDER BY` would not change anything, because it would apply to the result of the query, which is a single row.

Comment: This is interesting. If you take a look at my finished code, that I've inserted on the question today, changing the order by on the end from `ASC` to `DESC` changes the result returned as I expected. I'm just curious about if removing it from the end can mess up the order.

Comment: @rcdmk Oh my, this is the mother of all monstrous queries! I am surprised that the result changes with ORDER BY - you may want to look at the query plan to see why this happens,

Comment: LOL. Part of it is dynamicaly built because of so many duplicated blocks and conditions. I looked at the EP but I can't help myself with it.

Answer (score 1):

My inclination would be to leave the work in SQL, but restructure your query so it is not a union. You should be able to instead provide a stored proc that internal does a series of individual queries returns as soon as the result is found. Pseudo sql would start as something like this and could probably be improved along the way.

```
CREATE PROC GetBestSeller (Part, State, City, District) AS BEGIN

  DECLARE @Seller INT

  SELECT TOP 1 @idSeller = idSeller FROM your first choice

  IF @Seller IS NOT NULL BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM Seller WHERE idSeller = @idSeller
    RETURN
  END

  SELECT TOP 1 @idSeller = idSeller FROM your second choice
    SELECT * FROM Seller WHERE idSeller = @idSeller
    RETURN
  END

..and so one
END
```

EDIT: @Dasblinkenlight probably has the right of it in that the query optimizer in SQL Server would probably do this sort of thing internally and you could look at profiler to see if that was what was really happening with the UNION.

Comment: This is something to look at. Do someone have some comparison on this? I thought of asking before doing, but I think I'll have to do it anyway.